# default constructor & class pointer, overriding, inheritance problem

Tags: c++, class, pointers, inheritance, overriding

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Base {
    int x;
public:
        Base() : x() {}
    Base(int x) : x(x) {}
    virtual void print() const {
        cout << x << endl;
    }
};
```

on Derived(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}, Compiler said must usd "default constructor", but i'd thought that already made, and wonder why default constructor is needed.

```
class Derived : public Base {
    int x, y;
public:
    Derived(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
    void print() const override {
        cout << x << ", " << x << endl;
    }
};



int main() {
// All data members of Base and Derived classes must be declared 
// as private access types
    Base* p1 = new Derived(10, 20);     // (x, y)
    Base* p2 = new Base(5);         // (x) 
    p1->print();            // prints 10, 20
    p1->Base::print();      // prints 10
}
```

second in this problem,

```
p1->Base::print();      // prints 10
```

p1->Base::print() must print 10, but it didn't work. How can I print 10?

Comment: please include the complete verbatim error message in the question. do not paraphrase it

Comment: cannot reproduce. THe code you posted has no errors https://godbolt.org/z/W5K51aMz5

Comment: Both snippets work without any error. Refer to a [good c++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Unrelated, but you've forgotten the `virtual` destructor in the base class. Add `virtual ~Base() = default;`

Comment: `p1->Base::print() must print 10, but it didn't work.` because you didnt initialize `Base::x`. Please one question per question

Comment: If you attempted to get rid of those memory leaks using `delete`, your code exhibits undefined behavior due to the base class not having a virtual destructor.

Comment: ot: Why is there a comment `// prints 10` when it doesnt print 10 ? Sometimes I really dislike comments, they can be so confusion and misleading

Comment: Take `x` out of the derived class so you don't have two ints called `x` in play - there will be more to fix after that, but it will help.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it didn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your base class is missing a `virtual` destructor so trying to `delete p1;` will cause undefined behavior.
- `Derived` has 2 `x` member variables. `Base::x` and `Derived::x`. You most probably only want one. This also explains why `p1->Base::print()` doesn't do what you want. `Base::x` is `0` and `Derived::x` is `10`.
- `Base::x` is `private` so the `print` function in `Derived` should probably rely on `Base::print` to print it.

Example:

The base class here has a `virtual` destructor and the `print` function takes an `ostream&` so that it can print to *any* `ostream` (like `std::cout` or a file stream):

```cpp
class Base {
    int x;

public:
    Base() : x() {}
    Base(int x) : x(x) {}
    
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    virtual void print(std::ostream& os = std::cout) const {
        os << x; 
    }
};
```

`Derived` here does not add an `x` member variable, but initializes `Base` with the `x` value supplied to its constructor. The `print` function simply calls the base class `print`:

```cpp
class Derived : public Base {
    int y;

public:
    Derived(int x, int y) : Base(x), y(y) {}

    void print(std::ostream& os = std::cout) const override {
        Base::print(os); // calls `print` in the base class
        os << ' ' << y;  // and adds its own output
    }
};
```

You can also add an `operator<<` overload to make printing easier. Note that you only need one for the base class. It will call the `print` function in the most derived class:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Base& b) {
    b.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

The `main` function then becomes:

```cpp
int main() {
    Base* p1 = new Derived(10, 20);  // (x, y)
    Base* p2 = new Base(5);          // (x)

    std::cout << *p1 << '\n';   // 10 20
    std::cout << *p2 << '\n';   // 5

    p1->Base::print();          // 10

    delete p1;
    delete p2;
}
```

Or better, use smart pointers so that you don't forget to `delete` what you've allocated:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Base> p1 = std::make_unique<Derived>(10, 20);
    std::unique_ptr<Base> p2 = std::make_unique<Base>(5);

    std::cout << *p1 << '\n';   // 10 20
    std::cout << *p2 << '\n';   // 5

    p1->Base::print();          // 10
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/76KWe51qs)